# Is this a "global" :focus selector in Chrome? Can I overwrite it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, emotion

I'm working with React 16 and Emotion 10.0.7. The Emotion library is a CSS-in-JSS library one can use with React used to style components. I've got them working together and styling components. For the most part my CSS is being respected as "more specific" and overwriting other CSS as one would expect.

I'm trying to remove `:focus` outline from a button. I know this is frowned upon but I have been asked to do it for a work project.

My question is this. I have specified `'outline: none'` in my Emotion CSS mark-up at the component level. This gets translated into a class and the `:hover` pseudo-selector is applied to the class and then overwritten (I can see the strikethrough in Chrome Dev Tools) by the apparently "global" :focus selector in Chrome.

I am calling the pictured selector the "global" :focus selector for lack of a better term. Usually there is an indication of where the CSS is coming from (user agent, , some_file.css, etc) but here the top-right corner of the box is empty.

Is this a global Chrome selector for the `:hover` pseudo-class? Can I overwrite it or bypass it somehow? [global_hover_selector_chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr3kB.png)

Comment: no, "global rules" are marked as "user agent stylesheet"(see next block at your screenshot). rules you're asking about are created by js right in memory, that's why origin is not specified

Comment: have you tried `:focus { outline: none; }`?

Comment: Perhaps there was an error / clipping in the GUI of the chrome editor. After further testing the source was revealed to be the underlying index page, which was zealously styling all :hover pseudo classes with an !important tag. 

I'm not sure if this is a satisfying resolution for others, it was also rather confusing to me (the fact that index.js/html or whatever did not show in the top right of the GUI panel).